# Zend2 navigation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to make navigation buttons in my view, for example index.phtml but it's not working. I did know how to do it in Zend1 but in Zend2 I have a problem. My code looks like this (file index.phtml):

```
$container = new \Zend\Navigation\Navigation($tableActions);
var_dump($container);
echo '<div class="table-column">';
echo $this->navigation($container)->menu();
echo '</div>';
```

Variable $tableAction looks like this:

```
public $tableActions = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'On/Off',
        'module' => 'import',
        'controller' => 'import',
        'action' => 'setstatus',
        'params' => array('id' => null),
    ),
);
```

I did not get any error, just whole site die on this line. var_dump returns object(Zend\Navigation\Navigation) so it's fine so far. Problem is, how to show it...

Comment: Have you tried <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu->renderMenu($container) ?>   ?

Comment: Yeah, I just did, still the same thing. :(

Answer (score 0):

The navigation pages have dependencies which aren't being met by just creating a `new` container class in a view. The `Mvc` page needs a `RouteStackInterface` (Router) instance and a `RouteMatch` instance. Similarly `Uri` pages need the current `Request` instance.

You can see this clearly if you take a look at the [`Zend\Navigation\Service\AbstractNavigationFactory`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/Service/AbstractNavigationFactory.php) and its `preparePages` and `injectComponents` methods.

The view is not the right place to be instantiating menus, instead put the menu configuration spec in your `module.config.php`...

```
<?php
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'table_actions' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'On/Off',
                'module' => 'import',
                'controller' => 'import',
                'action' => 'setstatus',
                'params' => array('id' => null),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Write a factory extending the `AbstractNavigationFactory` class and implement the `getName()` method which returns the name of your menu spec key (`table_actions` in this example)

```
<?php
namespace Application\Navigation\Service;

use Zend\Navigation\Service\AbstractNavigationFactory;

class TableActionsFactory extends AbstractNavigationFactory
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getName()
    {
        return 'table_actions';
    }
}
```

Map the factory to a service name in the `service_manager` spec of `module.config.php` ...

```
<?php
return array(
    'navigation' => array(// as above ... )

    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
             'TableActionsMenu' => 'Application\Navigation\Service\TableActionsFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now you can call the view helper using the service name `TableActionsMenu` you just mapped

```
<div class="table-column">
    <?php echo $this->navigation('TableActionsMenu')->menu(); ?>
</div>
```

Finally, if, as I suspect, you need to change an attribute of the page depending on the view, you can do that too, navigation containers have [find* methods](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/AbstractContainer.php#L343-L357) which can be accessed from the navigation helper and used to retrieve pages.

Here's an example looking for the page with a matching page label, then changing it before rendering (obviously not an ideal search param, but it gives you the idea)

```
$page = $this->navigation('TableActionsMenu')->findOneByLabel('On/Off');
$page->setLabel('Off/On');
// and then render ...
echo $this->navigation('TableActionsMenu')->menu();
```